# плавное увеличение height

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Добрый день создал тестовый аккордеон хотел добавить плавности открытия и закрытия блоков но столкнулся с проблемой не могу увеличить высоту обьекта при выполнении ивента только при наведении. Вот собственно код подскажите как сделать плавное увеличение при срабатывании 'click'
P.S Чтобы было понятно что мне нужно надо навести на блок с фразой "Вы нашли скрытый текст"

```js
(function () {

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.block'),
      text = document.querySelectorAll('.text-block');

  //console.log(elems);

  Array.from(text).forEach(function (item, i, text) {
   // console.log(item.parentNode);
  //  console.log(i);
    item.parentNode.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     var active = document.querySelectorAll('.active'),
        activeText = this.children[1];
   //  console.log(active.length);
      if(active.length > 0) {
        activeText.classList.add('active');
        active[0].classList.remove('active');


      } else {
        activeText.classList.toggle('active');
        //activeText.style.height = 100 + 'px';
      }
   // animation1(activeText);
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
html body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body div span h2{
    display: block;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
h2 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.block-all {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #676664;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block div {
    display: none;
}
.block .active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.8s;
    -o-transition: height 0.8s;
    transition: height 0.8s;

}
.block .active:hover  {
    height:100px;

}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="block-all">
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: проблема в _display: none;_ это свойство не анимируется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете пользоваться `display: none` в CSS, чтобы реализовать плавное появление/изчезание объекта. Вы можете делать его `height: 0` либо с помощью JQuery `.fadeIn`/`.fadeOut`.

На вашем месте я бы оптимизировал JS и убрал все лишнее. По факту требуется просто докинуть/убрать класс `.active` при нажатии.

Что касается моих изменений: все было в рамках CSS стилей. Перенесли из `.active` все, кроме `height` свойства, добавили `height: 0`:

```js
(function () {

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.block'),
      text = document.querySelectorAll('.text-block');

  //console.log(elems);

  Array.from(text).forEach(function (item, i, text) {
   // console.log(item.parentNode);
  //  console.log(i);
    item.parentNode.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     var active = document.querySelectorAll('.active'),
        activeText = this.children[1];
   //  console.log(active.length);
      if(active.length > 0) {
        activeText.classList.add('active');
        active[0].classList.remove('active');


      } else {
        activeText.classList.toggle('active');
        //activeText.style.height = 100 + 'px';
      }
   // animation1(activeText);
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
html body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body div span h2{
    display: block;
    font-family: "Ubuntu", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
h2 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.block-all {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #676664;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block div {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.8s;
    -o-transition: height 0.8s;
    transition: height 0.8s;
}
.block .active {
    height: 20px;
}
.block .active:hover  {
    height: 100px;
}
.block h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="block-all">
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо буду знать=)

Answer (score 1):

При фиксированной высоте (как в коде вопроса) надо просто заменить `display: none;` на `height: 0; overflow: hidden;`. В случае же, если высота должна соответствовать контенту, то можно реализовать так:

```js
document.querySelector('.block-all').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var block = event.target.closest('.block');

  if (block) {
    var elem = block.querySelector('.text-block');
    
    if (elem.classList.contains('active')) {
      elem.style.height = getComputedStyle(elem).height;
      elem.classList.remove('active');
      getComputedStyle(elem).height; // reflow
      elem.style.height = '';
    } else {
      elem.classList.add('active');
      var h = getComputedStyle(elem).height;
      elem.style.height = '0';
      getComputedStyle(elem).height; // reflow
      elem.style.height = h;
      setTimeout(function () { elem.style.height = '' }, 1000); // Когда закончится анимация
    }
  }
})
```

```css
h2 {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block-all {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  height: auto;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #676664;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-block {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.8s;
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

.active {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-all">
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>Нажми на меня!</h2>
    <div class="text-block"><h3>Вы нашли скрытый текст!</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```